# Create a column of hyperlinks whose URL's depend on data in the table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, telerik, telerik-grid

I currently have a Telerik RadGrid whose columns are automatically constructed from data fetched with a stored procedure. I append a GridHyperLinkColumn to this grid, and my goal is to now set the hyperlinks in each cell of this column. My issue is that one of the parameters in each URL is a destination whose value can be found in the first column of the table.

The destinations are unique for each URL, so my goal is to somehow iterate through each hyperlink in the column and construct the URL based on the destination whose value is in the first column of the table. For example, in order to construct the URL for the hyperlink in row 4, I need to somehow access the value of the cell in the first column of row 4 and append this to the URL.

Is there any simple way to do this? I have searched for solutions but have come up empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the back-end stored procedure/sql query that returns the complete url instead of adding a column from the front-end code...